# Mouse events and block elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

In my documents I have a few divs with `text-align: center`:

```
<div>bla bla</div>
<div>bla bla bla bla</div>
<div>bla bla bla</div>
```

The problem is that while the content inside might not be large, the `width: 100%` of the divs potentially makes them a lot wider than the content. Mouse events are caught in all of the illustrated area:
[image]

I created my own custom tooltip in JavaScript, and having it appear when the mouse is so far off left or right from the content simply doesn't look right.

Instead, I would like for the tooltip to appear only when it hovers over the contents of the div, or at least make it look that way:
[image]

Setting the `display` of the divs to `inline-block` does size them down to the width of the content, but it also makes all the div appear in the same line.
Is there any way to achieve what I want without using `display: inline` and inserting `<br>`s between all the divs? This simply doesn't look like a convenient solution.

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments, another possible solution is to wrap the content of each div in a `span` element and add the mouse event to that, but that doesn't sound like a convenient solution either, especially since the content of the divs might be changed programmatically.

Comment: I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, so I'll put it as a comment. You can try wrapping the content within `<span>` and JSing the span's events.

Comment: @KodleeYin I've thought of that as well, but being forced to add a `span` element to every such div that needs a tooltip seems very tedious and inconvenient.

Comment: It's not inconvenient, it's very practical. You must have some trigger, and it can't be just some text, it must be class, Id, data attribute, tag, etc. So, making span with trigger and text inside is very ease to do.

Comment: @Aleksandar It's inconvenient to maintain as it will pollute the HTML code and make changing the content of the div via JavaScript more difficult if I want to avoid ruining the tooltip.

Comment: @Acidic I must agree with Aleksandar. I think it's very clear and very convenient to have spans inside of divs in your case. Yes, you will end up with some more elements but as long as you don't go crazy with the size of your website, I'm almost 100% certain, that you wouldn't notice any difference. And about the maintenability: it doesn't make changing the content any more difficult. Without spans, you would change the content of the div. With span, you just change the content of the span. Same task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the display type to table while also setting the margin to 0 auto will accomplish what you need.

```
div {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You also don't need text-align: center anymore for this to work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/NEqvD/

Comment: Interesting, at first glance this seems to work as intended... I'll have to test it.

Comment: Excellent, this solved the problem! I've used it in the following form to avoid overriding the top and bottom margins of the divs: `display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using floating: http://jsfiddle.net/3KH5k/1/.  Floats like absolute blocks, inlines, and inline-blocks shrinkwrap their content.

HTML:

```
<div>bla bla</div>
<div>bla bla bla bla</div>
<div>bla bla bla</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, but I must say that the bad support for `transform` kinda turns me off...